# Deploy AWS Lambda + API Gateway on Different Environments (Dev, QA, Demo etc) in Single AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

This might be a lame question but I am having a hard time getting an answer for this one. 
I have created an `AWS Lambda Function` which is being called from an `API Gateway`. I have used `aws-sam` for creating the template and deploying it on my AWS Account.

Now I want to deploy different versions of My `Lambda + API` on different environments such as Dev, QA, Demo, and Prod. But these different environments have to be on a single AWS account. Is there a way we can segregate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--stack-name` attribute to dictate what environment you are deploying to.

If you want to create a stack for a given environment (dev, test, prod, etc), use:

`sam deploy --template-file mytemplate.yml --stack-name dev`

This will create a stack called `dev` with all the resources isolated on it.

Comment: Is it right to use stack to differentiate between different environments?

Comment: yes, it is. If you are familiar with the Serverless framework it does the same thing as it also needs to use CloudFormation under the hood. Honestly, I don't think there's other way around it.